# Why I get Malformed UTF-8 data error on crypto-js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptojs

I try to encrypt and decrypt this string using `crypto-js`:

```
const str = `eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1aWQiOiI1ZDg5MjMxMjc5OTkxYjJhNGMwMjdjMGIiLCJoc2giOiIkMmEkMTMkWk53Y0cubjdRZFIybDA3S1RHd2RoLlN0QksudW5GSFVGLkZnZ0tQTGlUV2pOVEFqVy9SMm0iLCJncmFudCI6ImFjY2VzcyIsImlhdCI6MTU2OTI2ODUwMiwiZXhwIjoxNjAwODI2MTAyfQ.PQcCoF9d25bBqr1U4IhJbylpnKTYiad3NjCh_LvMfLE~3~null~undefined~434ce0149ce42606d8746bd9`;
```

But I got an error:

```
Error: Malformed UTF-8 data
```

What I doing wrong? How do I fix that?

The full code [also on stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-amo7i4?devtoolsheight=60):

```
import crypto from 'crypto-js';

const str = `eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1aWQiOiI1ZDg5MjMxMjc5OTkxYjJhNGMwMjdjMGIiLCJoc2giOiIkMmEkMTMkWk53Y0cubjdRZFIybDA3S1RHd2RoLlN0QksudW5GSFVGLkZnZ0tQTGlUV2pOVEFqVy9SMm0iLCJncmFudCI6ImFjY2VzcyIsImlhdCI6MTU2OTI2ODUwMiwiZXhwIjoxNjAwODI2MTAyfQ.PQcCoF9d25bBqr1U4IhJbylpnKTYiad3NjCh_LvMfLE~9~null~undefined~434ce0149ce42606d8746bd9`;

const cryptoInfo = crypto.AES.encrypt(str, 'secret').toString();

console.log({ cryptoInfo });
const info2 = crypto.AES.decrypt(str, 'secret').toString(crypto.enc.Utf8);

console.log({ info2 });
```

Comment: I think the parameters given are in a different order.  First data then secret.                
  _ crypto.AES.encrypt('secret', str).toString();_

Comment: I referred to this [crypto-js] (https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not sure why, but you have to **wrap your string with an object** and use `JSON.stringify` in order to make it works.

Here:

```
    import crypto from 'crypto-js';

    const str = `eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1aWQiOiI1ZDg5MjMxMjc5OTkxYjJhNGMwMjdjMGIiLCJoc2giOiIkMmEkMTMkWk53Y0cubjdRZFIybDA3S1RHd2RoLlN0QksudW5GSFVGLkZnZ0tQTGlUV2pOVEFqVy9SMm0iLCJncmFudCI6ImFjY2VzcyIsImlhdCI6MTU2OTI2ODUwMiwiZXhwIjoxNjAwODI2MTAyfQ.PQcCoF9d25bBqr1U4IhJbylpnKTYiad3NjCh_LvMfLE~9~null~undefined~434ce0149ce42606d8746bd9`;

    const cryptoInfo = crypto.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify({ str }), 'secret').toString();

    console.log({ cryptoInfo });
    const info2 = crypto.AES.decrypt(cryptoInfo, 'secret').toString(crypto.enc.Utf8);

    console.log({ info2 });

    const info3 = JSON.parse(info2);

    console.log({ str: info3.str });
```

Answer (score 5):

I encrypt a name and pass it as URL parameter.
I was supprised, that the decrypt code did not work
It was because of the "+" char generated in the encrypted parameter. Then using "encodeURIComponent" and "decodeURIComponent" it worked.

```
<script>
jQuery("#myBtn").click(function(){
    var clientname= jQuery("#myInput").val();
    var encrypted  = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(clientname, "secret key 123");
    //my URL to call with encrypted client name
    jQuery("#output").append('<small id="myurl">https://www.xxxxx.com/?id='+encodeURIComponent(encrypted)+"</small>");
});
</script>  



var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
var crypted_param = decodeURIComponent(urlParams.get('id'));
if(crypted_param && crypted_param != null && crypted_param != "" && crypted_param != "null"){   
    var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(crypted_param, "secret key 123");
    jQuery('#output1').val(decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
}
```

---

Answer (score 5):

You forgot to pass the encrypted text as parameter to decrypt function.

**In decrypt function you are passing original string, i.e. 'str'**  which  is causing the problem in above code, here is the corret code.

```
import crypto from "crypto-js";

const str = `eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1aWQiOiI1ZDg5MjMxMjc5OTkxYjJhNGMwMjdjMGIiLCJoc2giOiIkMmEkMTMkWk53Y0cubjdRZFIybDA3S1RHd2RoLlN0QksudW5GSFVGLkZnZ0tQTGlUV2pOVEFqVy9SMm0iLCJncmFudCI6ImFjY2VzcyIsImlhdCI6MTU2OTI2ODUwMiwiZXhwIjoxNjAwODI2MTAyfQ.PQcCoF9d25bBqr1U4IhJbylpnKTYiad3NjCh_LvMfLE~9~null~undefined~434ce0149ce42606d8746bd9`;

const cryptoInfo = crypto.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(str), "secret");

console.log({cryptoInfo});

const info2 = crypto.AES.decrypt(cryptoInfo.toString(), 'secret').toString(crypto.enc.Utf8);

console.log({ info2 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Despite all the above suggestions check your **Encryption Key** and **Secret Key**. While decrypting **Encryption Key** should match with your **Encryption Key** which you have used at the time of encrypting.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what caused the issue in my code

Answer (score 2):

```
export function encryptTheValue(word, key = 'yourkey') {
  const encJson = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(word), key).toString();
  const encData = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(
    CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(encJson)
  );
  return encData;
}

export function decryptTheValue(word, key = 'yourkey') {
  const decData = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(word).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
  const bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(decData, key).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
  return JSON.parse(bytes);
}
```

solution source [github](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/issues/271#issuecomment-691443875)

Answer (score 0):

Try this working example.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-ugh35d?file=package.json,test_crypto.js

Just run npm start in the terminal. if npm i is not done please do.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar issue where I was able to encrypt a file via C# and then send it to a NetSuite interface to have it decrypted via a javascript/node library. My very basic test CSV file (3x3) had no issues, but the customer had a file over 1.5 MB. I was able to find about 10 Unicode characters in the CSV data. Once we started sanitizing the data in the C# code (replacing the Unicode characters with the 3 char UTF-8 sequence
"[?]") we are able to get it to decrypt appropriately. Lots of testing and note that NotePad++ was one of the only free tools that would display these characters.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue while decrypting the file content.

If you are reading the content from the file, it should be converted to string as well.

```js
const data = readFileSync(filePath, { encoding: "utf8" });
```

Initially the error was due to,

```js
CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(data, secretKey).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
```

Later, I changed this to fix the error as below,

```js
CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(data.toString(), secretKey).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
```

Answer (score -2):

I was experiencing the same issue, it seems the encrypted value is base64 and needs to be converted to utf-8 first.
Example:

```
const utf8 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(value);
const decrypted = CryptoJS.DES.decrypt({ ciphertext: utf8 }, keyWords, { iv: ivWords });
```

I found the solution [Here](https://blog.fearcat.in/a?ID=00700-a1f4913a-7430-4beb-a3eb-ffed5e25818b)

Answer (score -3):

Might be this is slightly funny.. but this is how my senior has resolved this problem to me

We do have 2 different portals, assume XYZ portal and ABC portal (I am facing this issue in xyz portal)
ABC is the portal where we login.. to redirect to XYZ portal..

So in local I have opened both xyz portal and ABC portal.. and the issue is resolved..
(Earlier I opened only xyz portal so I was facing the issue) :D

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -6):

I've resolved my problem cleaning up the local storage.

[image]

Comment: Oh my God, this actually was the problem faced by me with the addition of crypto library and when the new build was deployed for testing. Thanks man